# Android UI gravity="right" doesnt work

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

Im trying to build a UI screen.
here is the main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.33"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/kartoMap"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/robotVideo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.66"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/stepsBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Steps"
            android:textOff="STEPS"
            android:textOn="STEPS" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ArmsBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Arms HOLDER" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/joystickRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/joystick" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/innerCircle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/inner_circle" />

    </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

The problem is in the ImageView called 'joystickRight'.
I want it to be tied to the right side of the screen, but instead - 
the frameLayout and the linearLayout are divided in the lower screen and the imageView stays in the center of the frameLayout. Why??

Answer (score 2):

Because the FrameLayout is set to wrap_content for both height and width.  So it is aligning right inside the FrameLayout which is only as wide as the imageviews.

Do this `FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"`

Comment: when I change to fill_parent the framelayout spend to the whole width of the screen , and indid the gravity="right" works but it spend outside the screen! there is a linear layout in the same "row" that "push" it outside...

Answer (score 2):

Try to add empty View inside horizontal LinearLayout between element that you want see left and element that you want to see right, e.g.:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />                

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's a thrash crutch, but only one which is working in my situation, thanks all the same)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `RelativeLayout` instead of `FrameLayout` and then for your joystickRight use the option of `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `android:layout_gravity="right" and the view will be aligned to the right within the parent.

Or you can do as Phobos suggested and make the view width "match_parent" and then `android:gravity` will work as you expect.